# How to fix headers that are scraped differently from what is published?

Tags: javascript, metadata

I use iWeb and iWeb seo tool to code my header and then upload by ftp

I've double checked the scripting before publish, but it constantly gives scrape errors such as "white space in image file name"

This is what I've coded:

```
<meta property="og:title" content=“Post Traumatic Stress Disorder - PTSD”/>
<meta property="og:description" content=“Counselling and Healing Post Traumatic Stress Disorder - PTSD”/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.ptsdcounselling.com/PTSDfbImage.jpg”/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.ptsdcounselling.com“/>
```

These are the scraped resuts

```
<meta property="og:title" content="&#x201c;Post" />
<meta property="og:description" content="&#x201c;Counselling" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.ptsdcounselling.com/PTSDfbImage.jpg&#x201d;/&gt; &lt;meta property=" />
```

Comment: You are using invalid quotes `“`, you should be using `"`

Comment: Wow! Spot on. Thank you so much Get Off My Lawn. I'm new. Can I give you points somewhere?